# flask_socketio import wont work, error: No module named flask_socketio

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

Im trying to create connection between flask socketio and react native socketio, I have already prepared client side with react native socketio BUT I have run into problem with importing flask_socketio in rpi. Im trying to use simplest implementation possible, this is my code:

```html
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World"
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5005)
```

Without line 2 it works perfectly but I need to use flask_socketio. here is photo too(first run is without importing flask_socketio, than I tried to import it and it wont work. I have tried reinstalling flask_socketio twice, rebooting but nothing works:/[image]:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem was that I was installing it with `sudo python pip install flask_socketio`, BUT I had to use python3, so right installation is `python3 -m pip install flask_socketio`

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to cmd prompt and use:

```
sudo -H pip3 install flask-socketio
```

Answer (score -1):

This might resolve your problem

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
```

this will work on any version of `socketio`